# Any way of achieving a 'permanent tooltip' type of feature in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, z-index, stackpanel

Basically I need a nicely formatted stackpanel to appear over a control - permanently. This stackpanel will overlap other controls if needs be. So what I'm trying to say is that it's equivalent in web design would be the highest of z indexes (not sure if this applies to wpf - I'm rather new to it).

Comment: will this link help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428622/building-a-reversible-stackpanel-in-wpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a second layer called the [Adorner Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) that you can use to...**adorn** other controls. When you add UI to the Adorner Layer, it sticks with the control it's adorning and always has the highest z-index over regular controls.

BTW the documentation says it's not possible to add an adorner using XAML, but through the magic of attached properties (or blend behaviors), it is indeed possible to use XAML elements to create adorners. I don't have an available sample but this [Codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CaAdornerBehavior.aspx) gives a good walk through

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're looking for an [Adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx).